# Trying to read command line switches with regex

Tags: c++, regex

So I am trying to read input from a command line in the format fileusage.exe [switches] [folder] where the switches can be typed in format as long as they start with a -. for example -c+j#R.

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    cout.imbue(locale(""));

vector<char> theSwitches;
regex switches(R"reg(\-(c|\+|j|#|w|s|x|r|R|S|v|h)$)reg");

if (argc > 1)
{

    // search through the command line args and find matching switches
    if (regex_match(argv[1], switches))
    {
        theSwitches.push_back(argv[1]);
    }
    else
        cout << "Didnt find the switches" << endl;

}
```

Comment: So what? What is your problem?

Comment: I want to be able to store the found char value for example if the user puts -r+c i want it to store r + c in theSwitches vector. My problem is it wont do that currently.

Comment: @MemeLord does your code compile? The problem you are asking to solve should be in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code, you will be able to iterate over the parameters. I have removed `$` as it would always match the end of parameter list.

```
regex switches(R"reg(\-(c|\+|j|#|w|s|x|r|R|S|v|h))reg");

std::string s = "-c -S";

using reg_itr = std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator>;
for (reg_itr it{s.begin(), s.end(), switches, {1}}, end{}; it != end;) {
    std::cout << *it++ << "\n";
}
// outputs:
// c
// S
```

Comment: Okay so I think I understand what your code is doing it helps. But my program accepts command line arguments as a char so the user would type "-cS" for example and the current way you have it set up if they type that it would just return c.

Comment: thank you man I figured it out just modified your code a little bit